# VLC trouble streaming

Tags: vlc, icecast

I'm trying to have VLC run on a hedless server to transcode an icecast stream from OGG to MP3. VLC will not begin streaming. Below is the command/output. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# sudo -u vlc vlc -I rc http://localhost:8000/live.ogg --loop --sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=64,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:gather:std{access=shout,mux=dummy,dst=liveEncode:*************@localhost:8000/live.mp3}"
VLC media player 2.0.6 Twoflower (revision 2.0.6-0-gbe9623c)
[0x8936d8] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
vlc: symbol lookup error: vlc: undefined symbol: libvlc_set_app_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the source is OGG, don't transcode for icecast.
Otherwise check "mp3" in preferences|stream|shoutcast